# Cannot get document.getElementById to run last

Tags: javascript, jquery, timeout, getelementbyid

I have a method:

```
function setSmartAlerts() {
        console.log(document.getElementById("uniform-DropDownObject").firstChild.innerHTML);
        console.log("Yay I'm running last!!");
    }
```

Which looks for the data inside the specified ID. I'm trying to force the method to run last to ensure that the data inside the target ID has populated. To do this I've tried all the following to no avail:

1)

```
setTimeout(setSmartAlerts, 9000);
```

2)

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        setSmartAlerts();
    });
```

3)

```
$(window).bind("load", function () {
        setSmartAlerts();
    });
```

All of the above has been placed both inside a $(window).load function (and outside it too) and positioned last in the document but I still cannot get this method to execute last. How can I get the setSmartAlert method to be executed last? I know this question has been asked a few times before, but all of the solutions posted haven't been able to resolve the above issue.

Comment: could you post the whole code? or a jsfiddle at least?

Comment: What do you mean by 'last'? Last as in, when the DOM is loaded, or as the last of all your JavaScript?

Comment: Actually this method shouldn't necessarily be run last. It is enough to run it after the document is loaded (to ensure the searching element exists).

Comment: What is setting the content inside of the element? Why is that not triggering something that says it is done?

Comment: Are you loading jQuery too? Because document.ready and window.bind are jQuery functions.

Comment: @Steyn Last as in, the element uniform-DropDownObject is a drop down box which holds some data. However my getElementById method fires too soon and returns nothing. I need to ensure that the setSmartAlerts() method goes last so that I know data within the drop-down box is loaded

Comment: @Steyn I am indeed, I tried using both javascript and JQuery to get this working

Comment: What is putting the content into the drop down?? I think you are trying solve a problem with the wrong solution.

Comment: @espascarello It's a call to the server which populates data inside a drop down box (which has the id mentioned in the question). Ensuring that has loaded first sounds ideal, do you have any ideas on how I would go about doing that? I've previously tried waiting on it before but it seems to think if the element has loaded so has the data (which wasn't the case)

Comment: So call the method when the content loading is done. Can you show how the content is being loaded?

Comment: @epascarello I'll give that a go, I've tried so many things already I can't remember what's already been done! I'll eat my phone if it was that simple! :) Unfortunately I can't show how it's being loaded as there are several calls all over the place (the code for this is somewhat old so it's gotten a bit messy over the years)

Comment: We expect the phone eating to be documented. By the phone you're eating, so please live-stream it instead of waiting until the end of the digestion process.

Comment: Hopefully it is not a Nokia or OP will destroy his jaws trying to chew it.

Comment: Samsung thankfully - tune in tonight on Twitch! (serious note: many thanks - fixed it by placing it after the part it was being set in)